# Check a certificate from iOS app

Tags: ios4, certificate, code-signing

I have a quite weird question. 
Is it possible to check in iOS app that the app is signed with a proper certificate?

I just give you an example: it's possible to download an app from some sites (won't give links here) than make some adjustments in app bundle, sign the app with the Apple Developer certificate (required registration as  an Apple Developer) and start the app on non-jailbroken devices.

The question is if I can check in the app that it was signed with my company certificate and not with some developer certificate?

Comment: Can you tell please did you find a solution?